# Apply class to element when I click on other element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, function

I want to write a function but I got a little problem.

I have a box that should expand when you click on another box, but there are multiple boxes and I just want one of them to be selected. My logic tells me to select `$(".class", this)` to select just the one box, but it does not work and I can't find another solution.

I would really appreciate your help. To give you a clear view on what I want to do, I just made a little wireframe in which you can see 3 steps:

1. Selecting the box on click
2. Applying styles to the other Box to expand it, and
3. In the same way I selected the second box I want to select another Element from the first box with a class and apply styles to it (it's an arrow that changed the direction from pointing to the top to point to the bottom, which means it's expanded).

Here is a sample of code to show what I want to do:

https://codepen.io/Lueh/pen/eVgNoa

Hope you understand what I want to do. I think it's a really easy answer and I just didn't think of it. By the way, I use jQuery for all of this.

[image: Idea wireframe]

// edit: I found a solution, I used the .next() jQuery selector after selecting my class and this. Check out the pen above, I included my solution in there.

Comment: I edited your question so now it's at least readable instead of a wall of text, but I have absolutely no idea what you're asking, or what you want to do

Comment: I thought I better write a big block of text to all can understand what I mean, It seems like I was wrong about it, so I try to explain it short:
I have a element which should be expanded on click and is selected by a class but I want to click on another element with a class to do it, because there are multiple elements with the same class I need to add a this selector somewhere - and theres the point, where should I add the this selector and which is the right syntax? I was trying $(".class", this) but it didnt select anything then.

Comment: That's a bit clearer :) Could you add a sample of your HTML to the question

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes of course, I edited my post above :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use ids instead of classes

```
$("#button").click(function(){
  $("#container").addClass("your-class")
})
```

to remove a class use `$("#container").removeClass("your-class")`

Or you can use siblings. Here's an example:

**HTML**

```
  <div class="container1">
    <button class="button">Button</button>
    <div class="box">
      Content1
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container2">
    <button class="button">Button</button>
    <div class="box">
      Content2
    </div>
  </div>
```

**JS**

```
$(".button").click(function(e){
    $(this).siblings(".box").addClass("hidden")
})
```

and a [JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/costya/k49qrex5/)

Comment: I would need to write a way to complicated function for this when I got like 1000+ elements with unique IDs instead of just one class.

Comment: I added another example where you don't need ids.

Comment: Thank you really much for your afford, I just found a similar resolution which worked for me, I kinda used the same code but I added the selector ".next()" instead of ".siblings()" :P

Comment: Sure. If this is also a working solution for you, do you consider accepting the answer? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- use an [on click event](https://api.jquery.com/click/) on a class (your boxes)
- in click event handler (select all elem via class, `.each` and ignore clicked one)
- `.addClass("...")` and or .`removeClass("...")` or [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

Good luck.

Comment: So I kinda want my function look like this, but the first line selects nothing instead of the elements with the class "box" and then just the one I clicked and not all of the elements with the same class:

$( ".box", this ).click(function() {
  $( .box__expand ).toggleClass( "box__expand--open" );
});

Comment: The trick is to work using class selectors, and in click event ignore currently selected element `$(this)`. If you still have trouble with this I recommend you work a bit on your jQuery skills.

Comment: Does not seems logical to me when I want to select an element with a class + this to ignore this when I didnt even can select it before... I just want the exact opposite of what you said I guess.. And yes I need to work on my jQuery skills thats why I'm asking something jQuery relevant in here. :D

Comment: Either select by id, select by class, or navigate to the DOM tree using `next`, `children`, ... to find nearby elements.